# jQuery addClass method chaining to perform CSS transitions

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

What I would like to do (**broke**):

```html
<div></div>
<button>go</button>
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').css({
        'transition': 'left 1000ms'
    }).addClass('left').addClass('left_more');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/13/

Still **broke**:

```html
<div></div>
<button>go</button>
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').css({
        'transition': 'left 1000ms'
    }).addClass('left');
    console.log('test');
    $('div').addClass('left_more');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwL3dwz2/3/

But this **works**:

```html
<div></div>
<button>go</button>
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').css({
        'transition': 'left 1000ms'
    }).addClass('left');
    console.log($('div').css('left'));
    $('div').addClass('left_more');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8x0dzbz/5/

I know I need a starting point for my CSS transition. That is why I added the `left` class.

Why does jQuery not do the transition until my #3?

## Update:

So I had accepted Stryner's answer, because it was working for me and now I'm having the same issue again. The above code was a simplified version of this JavaScript:

```
$('#screen_wrapper img:eq(0)').removeClass().addClass('prep'); //starting point
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('photo'+0)).left; //force the the styling to get recomputated using raw JavaScript 
$('#screen_wrapper img:eq(0)').css('left');//force the the styling to get recomputated using jQuery
$('#screen_wrapper img:eq(0)').addClass('animate_in');//animate to the "animate_in" class coordinates from the "prep" class coordinates
```

What's happening is that I'm getting the animation starting from coordinates prior to the `prep` class.

Here's the `prep` class:

```
#screen_wrapper img.prep {
    top: 0px;
    left: 506px;
}
```

But the image is actually starting from this class which is removed using the `removeClass()` jQuery method:

```
.animate_out {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0px;
    left: -506px;
}
```

The `transition` property is working properly:

```
$('#screen_wrapper img').css('transition','left 1000ms');
```

I have doubts that these **force** recalculation of styling:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('photo'+0)).left;
$('#screen_wrapper img:eq(0)').css('left');
```

I'm using Chromium:

```
Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
```

## Update

Example of it not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/me8ukkLe/12/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: I started off with what I would like to do?

Comment: I definitely saw the desired behavior, and some short code to reproduce the issue. Not sure what the point of placing that comment on this question was. Looks fine to me.

Comment: @TravisJ The original question only contained the description and the links to jsfiddle. I've inserted the code snippets from the fiddles into the question itself. Maybe the comment should have been added to the edit instead of the question...

Comment: @Andreas - Okay, I see what you mean in the revisions.

Comment: @Dusty I think the layout recalculation is still occurring. If I were to guess, the reason that the image starts from the removed class is due to the `transition`. When you force the recalculation, it starts transitioning to the value of the new class, but since you're instantly adding a new class after, that transition is getting interrupted. The reason this didn't occur in your original example is that the `<div>` had no initial `left` value to transition from. [If you add it, it does the same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/j8x0dzbz/9/). Also see http://jsfiddle.net/me8ukkLe/13/

Comment: @Stryner yeah I figured it out when composing this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002421/force-css-transition-to-update-multiple-times-in-javascript-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your transition works in case three when it calls `$('div').css('left')` because jQuery will call the method [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) (or a very similar method depending on browser compatibility issues). In [a blog post](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2012/09/css-transitions-for-dynamically-created-dom-elements/) by Tim Taubert (a Mozilla Employee), the trick is described:

> `getComputedStyle()` in combination with accessing a property value
>   actually flushes all pending style changes and forces the layout
>   engine to compute our `<div>`’s current state.

Without forcing this layout recalculation, the recalculation is delayed until after both classes (`left` and `left-more`) are added, which will calculate its position at `400px`.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j8x0dzbz/8/) - using `getComputedStyle` and accessing `.left`

Answer (score 1):

***"CSS3 transitions allows you to change property values smoothly (from one value to another), over a given duration."***

**1st Scenario posted :**

In order to have the `css` transition to work, you need to specify the `css` property to the element on which you want to do the transition. In your example, you are doing a transition on the `left` property but it's initial value is not defined in the `div css`.

In order to fix it, just add `left` property.

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/14/

**2nd scenario posted vs 3rd scenario posted:**

Even though both examples doesn't have `left` property defined for the `div`, the reason why the 3rd scenario works as compared to the 2nd scenario is because of the delay caused by `console.log`.

In the first statement,

```
$('div').css({
        'transition': 'left 1000ms'
    }).addClass('left');
```

`class` `left` is added to the `div` element, which internally adds the `left` property. But adding the console.log($('div').css('left') invokes window.getComputedStyle ( as mentioned by Stryner ) which registers the computed value and adding `$('div').addClass('left_more');` basically gives it an opportunity to perform the transition from `left : 100px` to `left : 600px`.

Comment: I believe @Dusty is looking for *why* the first two fiddles aren't working, as opposed to how to solve the matter.

Comment: added the explaination for that.

Comment: Example #2 uses a console log message as well

Comment: There is no "delay". The comment on the need for the property to exist is accurate though.

Comment: @TravisJ: Its kind of weird of an alert() statement substitute to console.log('test') solves the problem too. So i suspect it to be some kind of delay response

Comment: @DinoMyte - That is the result of the rendering engine calling the page to draw. It doesn't have to do with delay though. Stryner alludes to this in his answer as well remarking on the layout engine computing the values on the page: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33902053/1026459.

Comment: @TravisJ: Thanks. Didn't know what exactly console.log do behind the scene. Although If you notice closely, the alert() does create the transition ( no idea why )

Comment: @DinoMyte - Yes, perhaps I was not clear enough. The console.log doesn't cause any of this. The alert will draw to the view, and as a result the rendering engine is called. That is where the properties are updated for the element and the reason why when changed after that the transition occurs. Earlier, console.log was called with the argument $("div").css and the css function call in jQuery implicitly causes the rendering engine to recalculate property values as well.

Comment: @TravisJ: Got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! This behaviour definitely seems weird at first. It's also a little tricky to explain this clearly, but to start, understand the following:

**1) Javascript functions execute atomically**

In JS, functions always run from beginning to end without any possibility of some other operation occurring midway through. This is the same as saying that *JS is a single-threaded language*.

**2) The browser can't interrupt javascript either**

Not only is JS code prevented from running midway through a function, but the browser tab in which the code is running will also not interject! This means that (nearly) EVERYTHING on a webpage is halted (repaints, animations, stylesheet application, etc) when a JS function is running. If you want to test this, you can try running `while (true) { var i = 'yo'; }` in the console. (Warning: this will make you sad)

**3) State inside of JS functions is invisible to browsers**

Because the browser can't interrupt in the middle of a JS function it means the browser can never know any state that occurs mid-way through said function. The browser can only act based off of the state that remains once a function finishes. Not clear? To illustrate:

```
var someGlobalValue = null;

function lol() {
    someGlobalValue = 'hi';
    someGlobalValue = 'hello';
    someGlobalValue = 'ok';
}
```

When the function `lol` is run, `someGlobalValue` assumes multiple values, but the browser will *only ever be aware of the last one*, because it would have to interject midway through in order to see the others (which it can't do!)

**4) CSS State inside of JS functions is similarly invisible to browsers**

The same applies to css state! (And now you may see that I am, in fact, beginning to answer your question).

If you call the following function:

```
function lol() {
    $('.thing').css('left', '10px');
    $('.thing').css('left', '30px');
}
```

The browser will *never* apply the `left: 10px` value because it takes no actions midway through a function! Only the results of a function, one it is complete, can be worked with by the browser.

## Answering your questions!!

**fiddle 1**

The `left_more` class is added immediately after the `left` class - the browser never sees the `left` class, and applies css styling after the function ends - applying the `left_more` class, but since no initial left value was present there is no animation. (The css cascades; while both classes are present, `left_more` fully overwrites `left`)

**fiddle 2**

Same issue - the `left` class is overwritten before the browser can process it

**fiddle 3**

This works because the value is set with a call to `css`, and then is NOT overwritten because `addClass` is used to set where the value should animate to. The `console.log` is irrelevant - all that is important is the `css` function call. Once that function completes, there are 2 pieces of information, 1 being the `css` value, the other being the `class` value. This contrasts the other example where there is only *one* piece of information left after the function runs: the `class` value.

If you wanted to work with only classes, and still get the transition going, the flow would have to look like this:

1) Add `left` class
2) Exit function, which *allows the browser to view the state*
3) Add `left_more` class

Sry for the essay lol. But I think this needed a long explanation because of the subtlety of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues going on here. In the examples given, the reason that the transition does not occur when the first `left` class is added is because in order for the rendering engine to animate a property, that property needs to have a value already. In this case, there is no value for `left` and as a result the transition does not occur.

The reason why it does not work when chained is because of specificity. jQuery will add both classes and when the call to render the page is made the last added definition for left is applied due to their shared specificity.

The reason why it appears to work from adding the class at a separate time versus chained is because the rendering engine was implicitly called from jQuery when the console.log accessed the css values of the element. This was pointed out by Stryner in his answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33902053/1026459 . It was a very nice find.

Here is an example of that being applied so that the value of left doesn't need to be guessed at.

The meat of what happens is the offset of the element is found to get the pixel offset for left. Then that value is applied to the left style property. At that point while the element still hasn't changed position the rendering engine is called to update the left property. The property is then removed to ensure that the specificity does not take precedence over the class definition, and then the class definition is applied. This will facilitate the transition on first encounter.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/a3s5me8h)***

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').css({'transition':'left 1000ms'}).each(function(){ 
        $(this).css('left',$(this).offset().left); 
        window.getComputedStyle(this,null).getPropertyValue("left");
    }).css('left','').addClass('left');
});
```

```css
button {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

.left {
    left: 100px;
}

.left_more {
    left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>go</button>
```