# Force CSS transition to update multiple times in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I know how to get CSS transitions to work, but in this case I want to know **why** `getComputedStyle()` won't update the `right` class. Here's a reference to use the `getComputedStyle()` method to force style recalculation: [jQuery addClass method chaining to perform CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901533/jquery-addclass-method-chaining-to-perform-css-transitions)

An example of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8x0dzbz/8/

Now here's my fiddle of it not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/me8ukkLe/12/

And here's my code:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
     $('div div').eq(0).addClass('right');
     window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blue')).left; // FORCE "right" CLASS
     $('div div').eq(0).addClass('left_zero');
    });
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    position: absolute;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

button {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    left: -10px;
    transition: left 1000ms;
}

.right {
    left: 10px;
}

.left_zero {
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<button>go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `transition` property is on the `$('div div')` object, it is performing the transition, but the `left_zero` class is added so quickly that the element never gets a chance to transition to the `right` class coordinates. For this example the best thing to do is put the `transition` property on the `left_zero` class.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
     $('div div').eq(0).addClass('right');
     window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blue')).left; // FORCE "right" CLASS
        console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('blue')).left);
     $('div div').eq(0).addClass('left_zero');
    });
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid purple;
    position: absolute;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

button {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

div div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    left: -10px;
}

.right {
    left: 10px;
}

.left_zero {
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
<button>go</button>
```