# jQuery if (.scrollTop() < 100) only works on page load...?

Tags: jquery, animation, scrolltop

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I've got this little CSS animation that I want to start on page load, and whenever the user scrolls to the top of the page (or clicks on the nav link that takes them to the top). If I do it purely with CSS, it will only work once, on page load. So what I mean to do with jQuery is:

- check if page is scrolled less than 50px
- then remove the class that has the animation
- and finally reapply the class, to start the animation again.

My JS code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $('.restart').removeClass('animated');
      $('.restart').addClass('animated');
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section id="start">
  <div class="aufmacher">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Wir bieten</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="restart">Ambulante Versorgung</li>
        <li class="restart">Tagespflege</li>
        <li class="restart">Beratung &amp; Service</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes sliiide {
  0% { padding-left: 700px; }
  100% { padding-left: 0; }
}
.animated {
  animation: sliiide 1.5s 1;
}
.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}
```

[Find a JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/a27mtq23/2/)

I have to admit I don't really understand jQuery very well, it's mostly a copy and paste, trial and error thing for me. I've been searching the internet for quite a while now, and I *think* this should work, but it doesn't?

Any and all help is much appreciated! Also if there's a better way of doing this, please let me know. I'll be experimenting...

Thank you for your time,
Anna~

Comment: You're not giving the web page time to update. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901533/jquery-addclass-method-chaining-to-perform-css-transitions/33902053#33902053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling

```
$('.restart').removeClass('animated');
$('.restart').addClass('animated');
```

The UI thread never sees `.restart` without the `animated` class, so it doesn't start a new animation.

You can fix this by adding a `setTimeout` between the time you remove and add the classes, then when the UI thread sees a class being added (in a new event loop), it will re-run the animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#start').click(function(){
    alert($(window).scrollTop());
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 80) {
      $('.restart').removeClass('animated');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('.restart').addClass('animated');      
      }, 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes sliiide {
  0% { padding-left: 700px; }
  100% { padding-left: 0; }
}
.animated {
  animation: sliiide 1.5s 1;
}
.animated:nth-child(2) {
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.animated:nth-child(3) {
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

#start {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="start">
  <div class="aufmacher">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Wir bieten</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="restart"><span class="fa fa-check-square-o fa left"></span> Ambulante Versorgung</li>
        <li class="restart"><span class="fa fa-check-square-o fa left"></span> Tagespflege</li>
        <li class="restart"><span class="fa fa-check-square-o fa left"></span> Beratung &amp; Service</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/a27mtq23/4/

Comment: Brilliant, that indeed was the problem! Adding the timeout worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start').click(function(){
    //alert($(window).scrollTop());
    });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() < 80) {
         $('.restart').addClass('animated');
      }
      else
      {
         $('.restart').removeClass('animated');
      }      
   });
});
```

-removing and adding- immediately happens so fast it doesn't allow time to be evaluated. This explanation is not detailed, but if someone has a deeper one, please posted to allow our enlightenment.

Note: this is an idea, a posible solution, not a 100% tested thing. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing and re-adding the class, try removing and adding the element itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Use a bool here so you can detect when you want to reset the animation
  var reset = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 80) {
        if (reset) {

        //set to false so the animations only occur once
        reset = false

        //for each item to be animated, replace with new copy
        $('.animated').each(function(){
            var el = this;
            var clone = el.cloneNode(true);
            el.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, el);
        });
      }
    }else {
        //prepare for reseting animation
        reset = true
    }
  });
});
```

Don't forget to add the animate class to the proper elements so that they animate on load

```
<section id="start">


<div class="aufmacher">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Wir bieten</h1>
        <ul>
        <li class="restart animate">Ambulante Versorgung</li>
        <li class="restart animate">Tagespflege</li>
        <li class="restart animate">Beratung &amp; Service</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```